Issue with large configuration files leading to 413 errors in Amplify Agent POST requests
My NGINX setup includes a primary nginx.conf file that makes extensive use of the include directive to incorporate numerous additional configuration files, each corresponding to a distinct domain managed by my server. This approach is critical to my deployment strategy, allowing for modular management of server blocks and streamlined updates.
However, I've observed that the NGINX Amplify Agent attempts to send all these configuration files as part of its POST request to the Amplify server. Given the substantial number of included configuration files, the size of the request payload becomes significantly large. Consequently, this results in the server responding with a "413 Client Error: Request Entity Too Large" status code, preventing successful data transmission.
Upon reviewing both the Amplify documentation and the agent's source code, I could not find an option or setting that would allow me to limit or exclude certain configuration files from being sent. Adjusting my deployment strategy to reduce the number of included files would be quite challenging at this stage, so I am seeking an alternative solution that would enable the agent to report without transmitting an excessively large payload.
Could you please advise on how to address this issue? Is there a configuration option available to limit the scope of configuration files sent by the agent, or any other recommended workaround that would prevent these 413 errors while ensuring continued comprehensive monitoring of my NGINX environment?
Thank you for your attention to this matter. I look forward to your guidance and am happy to provide any further details or clarification you may require.

open up a ticket on the vendor and verify with them, due its a third party software. and what is in your mind a "large configuration"?

I've posted an issue in their github repository an year ago with no replies :/  Also tried to contact their support, but they provide support through my.f5.com and you need to have a subscription or be a paid member of nginx plus :/

Thank you @djdomi, my nginx.conf is only a few kbytes but I include several .conf files from a directory. I have around 700 domains and I use a .conf file for every domain. In total it's about 100Mb. I've checked the Amplify's log and I can see it tries to make a POST request of 27Mb (it uses gzip), but it seems their service is configured to accepts POST request below that number. I couldn't find any clarification on this matter.

i dont think they monitor github, but creating a case on https://my.f5.com/manage/s/ might help more

Thank you @djdomi, I was able to create a case, I'll leave this post opened and I'll post here whatever answer they give me.
